# Calculate weighted sum; criteria amount can be less than amount of alternatives; indexes match loosely

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two dataframes. I desire a weighted sum of these, like so:

```
ws[0] = a1[0]*c1[0] + a2[0]*c2[0] + a3[0]*c3[0] + ...
ws[1] = a1[1]*c2[1] + a2[1]*c2[1] + a3[1]*c3[1] + ...
ws[2] = a1[2]*c2[2] + a2[2]*c2[1] + a3[1]*c3[1] + ...
...
```

The indexes are dates. The difficulty is that

- amount of criteria can be less than amount of alternatives
- some criteria date indexes match alternatives date indexes loosely

So if corresponding criteria is missing, then the previous criteria should be taken. If criteria date index `>` alternative date index then

- previous alternative should be taken
- previous criteria should be taken

Let's say we have a two dataframes:

- The `alternatives` dataframe:

  ```
  date         a1       a2      a3

  2018-01-01   10.00    10.00   10.00
  2018-01-02   20.00    10.00   10.00   
  2018-01-03   20.00    20.00   20.00   
  2018-01-13   10.00    20.00   30.00
  ```
- The `criteria` dataframe:

  ```
  date         c1        c2       c3

  2018-01-01   0.10      1.00     1.00
  2018-01-05   1.00      0.50     1.00   
  2018-01-13   1.00      1.00     1.00
  ```

So the result should be following:

```
date         ws

2018-01-01   21.00   # alternative date == criteria date, all systems nominal
2018-01-02   22.00   # criteria date > alternative date, taking 2018-01-02 alternative && 2018-01-01 criteria 
2018-01-03   42.00   # criteria date > alternative date, taking 2018-01-03 alternative && 2018-01-01 criteria  
2018-01-13   60.00  # alternative date == criteria date
```

Dear pandas magicians, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct, that you want result, that includes all dates from `alternatives`, but if date is not in alternatives it should be dropped? If so, here is solution:

```
alternatives_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['20180101', '20180102', '20180103',
                                       '20180113'])
criteria_dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['20180101', '20180105', '20180113'])

alternatives = pd.DataFrame(
    index=alternatives_dates, columns=['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 
    data=[[10, 10, 10],[20, 10, 10], [20, 20, 20], [10,20,30]]
)
criteria = pd.DataFrame(
    index=criteria_dates, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], 
    data=[[0.1, 1, 1],[1, 0.5, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
)

merged = (alternatives.merge(criteria, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
                      .dropna(subset=['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])
                      .fillna(method='ffill'))
result = merged['a1']*merged['c1'] + \
         merged['a2']*merged['c2'] + \
         merged['a3']*merged['c3']

print(result)
# date
# 2018-01-01    21.0
# 2018-01-02    22.0
# 2018-01-03    42.0
# 2018-01-13    60.0
# dtype: float64
```